# How to know what causes "Timer fired" in angular

Tags: angular, zone

My angular app has a lot of "Timer fired" events those are invoked from zone-evergreen.js

[image]

I would like to examine what is the cause of these events.
How can I do this?

Angular version is 11.2.9.